# Char stolen by regex

Tags: regex

I want to get the Level 1-Markdown Heading by this regex

`/^\#[^\#]\s*(.+?)\s*\#*\n+/m`

This is the input:

`##Invalid##`

`#Valid#`

`##Invalid`

`#Valid`

I expect this: `Valid` but I get this: `alid`. 
Whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the regex engine you are using and also provide a valid and an invalid example of strings that use the whitespace you are trying to exclude by `\s*`, please? (I can imagine what the latter would look like, but I want to make sure I am thinking of the same problem as you are.)

Comment: Do you want `#text with spaces#` to match?

Comment: Also, do you want to capture `#text with # in the middle#` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have over complicated your expression.

The following matches the start of a line, then one `#` character, then anything but an `#` character, then optionally matches one `#`, and then the end of the line.

```
^\#([^\#]+)\#?$
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/ji8q1j)

### Output

```
##Invalid## => No Match
#Valid#     => #(Valid)#
##Invalid   => No Match
#Valid      => #(Valid)
#Invalid##  => No Match
```

If you really don't want the outside white space in the group, you can use the following expression witch adds optional white space in between the `#` characters and group:

```
^\#\s*([^\s\#]+)\s*\#?$
```

### Output

```
##Invalid##     => No Match
#Valid#         => #(Valid)#
##Invalid       => No Match
#Valid          => #(Valid)
#Invalid##      => No Match
#  Valid  #     => #  (Valid)  #
#  In Valid?  # => No Match
```

Comment: I use this regex (build on yours): ```/^\#\s*([^\#]+)\s*\#?[^\#]+$/m```

Answer (score 0):

`[^\#]` will eat one character that is not `#`. In your case, that is your `V` character.

If your regex engine supports look-ahead, you can probably use that to determine whether the next character after the initial `#` will be a whitespace (do not include in recognized headline text or anything else except for a `#` (do include in recognized headline text).

Otherwise, the probably easier way to go would most likely be to include the whitespace in the capturing group and **trim the string afterwards** in your host language:

```
/^\#((?:\s|[^\#]).*?)\s*\#*\n+/m
```

This will consider the initial series of `#` signs finished as soon as either a whitespace or a non-hash sign is found (both of which are included in the capturing group). (Note that I'm using the `(?:)` syntax for the inner non-capturing group, which might look differently for your particular regex engine). The remaining characters of the inner text will then be gathered as in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by O. R. Mapper `[^\#]` is stealing the `V`, you could use something like this instead:

```
(^|[^#])#\s*([^#]+?)\s*(#($|\r?\n)|($|\r?\n))
```

Group 2 would contain the inner text

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?35t6u)

Comment: In this case, the optional initial whitespace of the inner text would be included in the capturing group, unlike what the OP seems to be trying.

Comment: Your Regex is correct, but does not account for spaces, that OP is apparently afraid of, since he used '\s' before and after the group...

Comment: The OP uses `.+` to recognize the inner text, which implies that `#` *within* the inner text is fine and should not be excluded.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `.+?` is the inner text, making it ungreedy and not capturing `\s*#*` - restricting any hashes from being matched inside

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Hmm ... indeed. At least in SO's markdown implementation, `# #A` seems to be interpreted as the level-1 headline `#A`, though. Let's wait for more examples by the OP to see what he or she actually wants.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: But then, it requires at least one newline `\n` to follow after the optional final space(s) and closing hash(es) `\s*\#*`, meaning that in a line like `#abc#abc#\n`, the middle hash would very well be captured.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper True.. I've added another question to the original question - more clarification needed here

Comment: @DanielGimenez Updated, though as discussed with O.R. Mapper - we still need more info, including whether or not the test string is `#item#` or `#item#\n#another item#\n#blah#`

Answer (score 0):

how about this regex:

```
^#([^#]*)#?$
```

if you want to strip the spaces:

```
^#\s*([^#]*?)\s*#?$
```

Comment: In this case, the optional initial whitespace of the inner text would be included in the capturing group, unlike what the OP seems to be trying.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper 2nd line added

Comment: I *think* that if there is some initial whitespace, then the inner text is allowed to contain `#`. Note that the OP uses `.+` in the inner text, meaning that `#` is indeed allowed in the inner text. At least in SO's markdown implementation, `# #A` seems to be interpreted as the level-1 headline `#A`.